# Get the correct value to use for scrolltop(int) when using meta viewport

Tags: jquery, viewport, scrolltop

I am working on a mobile website project that is using the following script to scroll over the main menu and go to the content:

```
function getMenuHeight(){
    var full = "#menuid";
    var height = $(full).height();
    return (height);
}
function scrollPastMenu(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: getMenuHeight()}, 750);
}
```

which works perfectly, until I set the viewport of the website, then it scrolls way to far. How can I determine the correct value to use for scrollTop(value), when having the viewport set up like `width=320; initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1; user-scalable=0;` ?

EDIT: fixed this by using document.ready!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work if your timing is okay.